# Set focus on PasswordBox when application starts

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there a reason why I can't set the focus on my PasswordBox Control?

#### C#:

```
public Login()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   _password.Focus();
}
```

#### XAML:

```
<PasswordBox x:Name="_password" Width="200" Height="30" FontSize="14" 
 KeyDown="_password_KeyDown"/>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're doing it too early when you're setting it in the constructor. Try the Load event handler instead.

```
public Login()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Login_Loaded);
}

void Login_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _password.Focus();
}
```

You can also do it in XAML:

```
  <Window ....
        FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=_password}"
         ... />
```

Comment: Interesting, is it nested in another container?

Comment: it's in the same StackPanel where _userName is and it can focus to _userName but can't to _password. Does it matter if _userName is TextBox and _password i PasswordBox?

Comment: As long as they're input controls it shouldn't matter, but I think you can place that WPF FocusManager.FocusedElements directive on the StackPanel instead and see if that works (obviously you'll have to comment out the line of code!)

Comment: in StackPanel it does work as well. But C# works better for me as i need if statement. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3):

WPF offers a nice elegant way (xaml only)

```
FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=pass}">
```

Example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=pass}">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="261,165,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="70,193,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="pass" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="70,165,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

Comment: pl one for gif file

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in `XAML`:

```
<StackPanel FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=_password}">
   <PasswordBox Name="_password" />
</StackPanel>
```

Please note ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768(v=vs.110).aspx)):

> There can be only one element on the whole desktop that has keyboard
>   focus. In WPF, the element that has keyboard focus will have
>   IsKeyboardFocused set to true.